# Expectation of random 2d walk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Start at the origin, take $n$ independent steps of length 1 in the direction of $\theta_i$, which is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$.

If $X,Y$ is the position after $n$ steps and $D = X^2 + Y^2$, what is $E[D]$?

Comment: Please do not delete posts after you got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that a move of length $1$ in the direction $\theta$ is a translation by the vector $e^{i\theta}$, where $i^2 = -1$. 
Thus, if $D: = (X,Y)$ is the position after $n$ moves on the (complex) plane, then
$$
D = e^{i\theta_1} + ... + e^{i \theta_n} \in \mathbb{C},
$$ 
hence
$$
|D|^2 = D \overline{D} = \sum\limits_{k,m=1}^n e^{i(\theta_k - \theta_m)} = n + \sum\limits_{1\leq k \neq m\leq n}^n e^{i(\theta_k - \theta_m)}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\mathbb{E} |D|^2 = n + \sum\limits_{1\leq k \neq m\leq n}^n \mathbb{E} e^{i(\theta_k - \theta_m)} = n +  \sum\limits_{1\leq k \neq m\leq n}^n \mathbb{E}e^{i\theta_k} \mathbb{E}e^{-i \theta_m} = n,
$$
where we used the independence of $\{\theta_k\}$, and the fact that $\theta_k \sim U[0,2\pi]$ for concluding that $\mathbb{E}(\theta_k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} e^{ix} dx = 0$.

Comment: Can you clarify the indexes on your second line of equations?

Comment: @jdoe, first we multiply all pairs $e^{i\theta_k}$ and $e^{-i\theta_m}$ where $1\leq k,m \leq n$. When in these pairs $k=m$, the complex exponential becomes $1$ and we have $n$ such instances of such pairs. Hence, the second sum on the second displayed formula runs over all $k,m$ from the range $1...n$ which does not coincide.